# Define constant based on device type

Tags: iphone, objective-c, constants, device, definition

I have a Constants.h file which contains some global constants in fact. Since my application is built both for iPhone and iPad, i would like to define the same constants (ie with the same name) differently for the two device types.

For a complete explanation:

```
/******** pseudo code *********/

if (deviceIsIPad){
    #define kPageMargin 20
}
else {
    #define kPageMargin 10
}
```

How can I do this?
Thanks.

L.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's impossible to get device type during preprocessing step. It is determined dynamically during runtime. You have two options:

1. Create two different targets (for iPhone and iPad respectively) and define macro there.
2. Create macro that inserts expression like this:

> ```
>  #define IS_IPAD    (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
>
>  #define kMyConstant1 (IS_IPAD ? 100 : 200)
>  #define kMyConstant2 (IS_IPAD ? 210 : 230)
>  #define kMyConstant3 (IS_IPAD ? @"ADASD" : @"XCBX")
> ```

Comment: I think i'll try the second option an if it works properly I'll mark your answer as correct :)

Comment: Awesome, you've saved me so much time!

Answer (score 2):

`#define` are resolved at compile time, ie on your computer

Obviously, you can't make them conditional the way you want. I recommend creating `static` variable and setting them on the `+(void)initialise` method of your class.

And for the condition, use something like

```
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {   
    // iPad 
} else {   
    // iPhone or iPod touch. 
}
```

So that would go

```
static NSInteger foo;

@implementation bar

+(void)initialise{
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {   
        // iPad 
        foo = 42;
    } else {   
        // iPhone or iPod touch. 
        foo = 1337;
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: Use it on your AppDelegate class, that way it will be accessible throughout the app

Answer (score 0):

Hi write this code in `appdelegate` class

```
    +(NSString *)isAppRunningOnIpad:(NSString *)strNib{
    NSString *strTemp;
    NSString *deviceType = [UIDevice currentDevice].model;
    if ([deviceType hasPrefix:@"iPad"]){
        strTemp=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@I",strNib];
    }
    else{
        strTemp=strNib;
    }
    return strTemp;
}
```

call this from your class using this line

```
SecondVC *obj_secondvc = [[SecondVC alloc] initWithNibName:[AppDelegate isAppRunningOnIpad:@"SecondVC"] bundle:nil];
```

Comment: This is not a class, it is an header file, therefore it is never initialized an i can't call methods from there..

Answer (score 0):

Use UIDevice Macros - http://d3signerd.com/tag/uidevice/

Then you can write code like;

```
if ([DEVICE_TYPE isEqualToString:DEVICE_IPAD]) {

}
```

or

```
if (IS_SIMULATOR && IS_RETINA) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with defines, as they're expanded at compilation time. However, you can define variables and set their initial value based on the user interface idiom:

```
// SomeClass.h
extern CGFloat deviceDependentSize;

// SomeClass.m
- (id)init
{
    // ...
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad])
        deviceDependentSize = 1024.0f; // iPad
    else
        deviceDependentSize = 480.0f; // iPhone


    // etc.
}
```